# Meaning of "our eares are converted into cates"

Tags: meaning, archaicisms, early-modern-english, puns

In Archie Armstrong's Banquet of Jests (1641 edition), there's [an account of a punning clergyman](https://play.google.com/books/reader?id=G5RBAAAAYAAJ&pg=GBS.PA106&hl=fr_CA):

[image: screenshot]

> A DIVINE willing to play more with words than to be serious in the expounding of his Text, made his wit runne descant in this manner. This Diall, saith he, shewes wee muust die all ; yet notwithstanding, all houses are turned into Alehouses ; our eares are converted into cates ; our Paradice into a pare of Dice ; our Marriage to a Merry age ; our Matrimony, to a matter of money ; *It was not so in the dayes of Noah, ah no, &c.*

What are these "eares" and "cates"? I certainly don't see much of a pun if it were "ears" and "cats", for example...

Comment: This would have been type-set from a hand-written original. Possibly "eares" should be "cares".

Comment: @Peter Ah, that's a likely start at aligning them!

Comment: It's obvious from the context *(**Diall => die all, all houses => alehouses, paradise => pair of dice, marriage => merry age**)* that ***eares => cates*** can't be right. I found several different OCR errors for that bit, but ***cares => cures*** (or vice-versa) is certainly consistent with the other examples. It's meaningless to ask for "meaning" here, though - the text is 90% about wordplay, and only 10% about the semantics.

Comment: @FumbleFingers If one assumes that they're errors there's no point asking about them, but if one assumes that they might be archaic words one hasn't yet heard, there is a point. A savvier asker than I might have done what you and Sven did and compared editions for OCR errors, but differences in savviness are why we ask questions. (Not that I actually used the word "meaning". But for what it's worth, I don't agree that its being wordplay implies that the meaning is irrelevant, since the puns turn on the moral implications of linking the meanings; they're not just random pairs of soundalikes.)

Comment: Well, the entire context is "light-hearted humour, entertainment", so I see a certain amount of consistency in all the *other* transformations (although to fit initial ***die all*** into the pattern, I have to assume allusion to ***Eat, drink, and be merry, for tomorrow we die***). But although it works at the phonological level, I can't really fit ***cares => cures*** into the general pattern at the *semantic* level. Having ***cures*** might be an *improvement* over having ***cares***, but they're not exactly "entertaining, light-hearted" like the others.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Indeed, the pattern — particularly with the context that it's a divine saying it — is certainly that our judgement day is coming, yet ("notwithstanding") people are blithely going on eating, drinking, making merry, gambling, debasing what is sacred, and so on. (My interpretation is that the entertainment is less in the puns themselves and more in the idea that a preacher would think it best to give such a message through punning.) I agree about the difficulty of fitting cares/cures into that rubric; see my open question under Sven's answer.

Comment: Ooops! I'd noticed ***A divine*** (antiquated ***a clergyman***) at the beginning, but it never even occurred to me he might be talking about ***Judgement Day.*** It's *slightly* odd to be punning on ***die all*** for an event where everyone (or at least, the "lucky" ones) gets ***resurrected,** brought **back** to life*. But if you believe in the Second Coming, I suppose it's perfectly reasonable to assume that on that happy day, earthly cares will transform into heavenly cures. Whatever - I no longer think "Eat drink and be merry..." is relevant.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yeah, a little odd if you think about it as a happy day of resurrection for all, but less so if you think of it as judgement. "Your earthly life will end and you'll meet your maker; are you living right?" is a common enough theme for a preacher.

Comment: But of course there wasn't *really* any such preacher for the cited text! That "Divine" is the equivalent of the Englishman, the Irishman, and the Scotsman (who get up to all sorts of capers in Jokeland, just not in the real world! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Indeed, they just serve as premises. The whole book of jests, which is quite fun to read, is full of preachers and lawmen bumbling about and looking silly, and many of the cases are so far-fetched they barely work as jokes! But here's [a good one I asked about on Latin SE](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/16604/qui-mihi-decipulus) where the parson is the one who comes out on top at the expense of a gentleman who wants to look smart.

Comment: If it is cures and cares, then, based on the pattern of the others, I would think it would be "our cures are converted into cares" and not the other way around. Oh, well, not according to the answer. Oh well.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is the version of the relevant passage from the original text of Archie Armstrong, [*A banquet of ieasts. Or Change of cheare Being a collection of moderne jests. Witty ieeres. Pleasant taunts. Merry tales.*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo2/A03559.0001.001/1:5.133?ALLSELECTED=1;c=eebo;c=eebo2;g=eebogroup;rgn=div2;singlegenre=All;sort=occur;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;xc=1;q1=our+cares+con%E2%88%A3uerted) (1630) as rendered at Early English Books Online:

> A Diuine willing to play more with words, then to be serious in the expounding of his text, spake thus in some part of his sermon; this Dyall shewes wee must dye all, yet notwithstanding, all houses are turned into Ale-houses: **our cares conuerted into cures**: our Paradice into a paire of Dice: our mariage to a merry age: our Matrimony to a matter of money: our Diuines into dry Vines: It was not so in the dayes of *Noah*, Ah no, &c.

So the wording given as "our eares are converted into cates" in the posted question is (according to EEBO) actually "our cares converted into cures" in the original text. All of the conversions mentioned in this passage are puns of one degree or another.

On the other hand, a [1639 edition of this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=FUpnAAAAcAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22banquet+of+jests%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjP8Krg-NGDAxXiMUQIHQEbAE8Q6AF6BAgJEAI#v=onepage&q=%22paradice%22&f=false), billed as "the fifth Impression, with many Additions," renders the passage as follows:

> A Divine willing to play more with words, than to be serious in teh expounding of his Text, spake thus in some part of his Sermon : this Dyall shewes we must die all, yet not withstanding, all houses are turned into Alehouses : our cares are turned into Cates : o[u]r Paradice into a Payre of Dice : our Marriage into a merry age : our Matrimony, into a matter of money ; our Divines dry Vines : It was not so in the dayes of *Noah, Ah no, &c.*

So the transition from *cures* to *Cates* came rather early in the publishing career of this book, if indeed it was not *cates* from the outset. Yet notwithstanding nought of wit standing, we have a choice choice of *choses* wherefrom to choose.

Nathan Bailey, [*An Universal Etymological English Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=sM2uyrbP7CkC&pg=PP673&dq=%22pottage%22+%22potage%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi5uaD34Yv5AhUJKUQIHUSoAII4KBDoAXoECAgQAg#v=onepage&q=%22cates%22&f=false) (1721) offers this brief entry for *cates*:

> **CATES** {Cates, *Goth.* Delicacies} dainty Victuals.

But it isn't clear to me how common *cates* was in seventeenth-century English. It doesn't appear in any of the dictionaries prior to Bailey's that I checked—but most earlier dictionaries were reserved for "difficult" words and *cates* may not have qualified as such.

In any case, a pun running *cares* into *cates* is not appreciably cleverer than one running *cares* into *cures*.

Comment: Shakespeare has Petruchio pun on _cate_ and _Kate_ in 'The Taming of the Shrew'.

Comment: Great sleuthing! Interesting that the sense deteriorated in two separate stages, one of them going undetected for centuries??, to get to the nonsense in the Google Books edition.

Comment: What do you make of the 'cares/cures' pun? The others all have pretty clear imports, but this one is more ambiguous to my mind. Simply that our ills will turn to good at the last day (mourning into dancing kind of thing)? Or our worries/troubles are somehow linked to our salvation? Or because the others all run the other way, maybe 'cares' is the one with the positive sense (our legitimate concerns) and 'cures' the negative (quick remedies)?

Comment: Except for 'dial' (clock) --> to 'die all', most of the puns tend in the direction from serious to frivolous, and the cure for care may simply be insouciance. But 'dry vines' aren't jollier than 'divines'; they're just less substantial. And the 'Noah' --> 'ah no' wordplay is no more than a kind of sound-based palindrome. So the jests are scattershot and may not serve any deeper point. Bailey's 1721 dictionary offers this entry for 'cure': 'the healing of a Distemper or Wound ; Also a Benefice or Spiritual Living with the Charge of Souls.' But I doubt that the punster has 'curates' in mind.

Comment: As a followup to "our cares converted into cures," I note that in "Love's Labour's Lost" Rosaline, in a banter with Katharine, has the line "Great reason ; for 'past cure is still past care'—suggesting that "converting cares to cures" may allude to an inversion of this old aphoristic relationship between the two, wherein cares may be nullified by cures.

Answer (score 6):

No answer here yet, but a placeholder . . .

Here is an image of what appears to be the first publication, in 1630, of *A Banquet of Jests* — “Never before Imprinted.” We see there: ***our cares converted into cures***:

[image: A Banquet of Jests, 1630]

The next earliest one I could find was from 1634 — “The fourth Impression, with many Additions.” We see there: ***our cares are converted into Cates***. (Note that the word *Cates* also appears on the page to the left of the title page.)

[image: A Banquet of Jests, 1634]

My current angle is: We’re all going to die, but nowadays, we pursue earthly delights, because we have what Noah didn’t: Jesus to forgive our sins.

...And before the *Cates* edit, we had drink, gambling, sex, and money. Food (*cates*) was clearly missing.

But the author was clearly on a punning (sound-alike) streak — dyall/dye all,  all houses/ale-houses, paradice/paire of dice, mariage/merry age, matrimony/matter of money, divines/dry vines — and cares/cates doesn’t fit in there. If cares/cures doesn’t quite cut it, I would still go back to 1630 to look for clues.

Comment: I like how the first word of the next page is also printed at the end of the page, presumably to make it easier when reading aloud.

Comment: Very interesting, and suggests that 'cures' was either mistaken in the first place or deemed inferior to 'cates' early in the publication history. The fact that the 'divines / dry vines' pun was also dropped hints at the intent to improve rather than a random typo.

Comment: Now I'm very curious to know what is supposed to be humorous about the story _of Bishop Gardiner_. It has clearly gone over my head.

Comment: @A.R.: I think the joke there is nothing more than this exchange: Random fellow (with an exaggerated bow): "Good morrow, onetime bishop." Ex-bishop Gardiner: "Thank you, permanent knave." Henny Youngman it ain't.

Comment: @SvenYargs Aha! I hadn't pegged _Olim_ as being Latin. The author's bizarre use of Italics to mark all the other proper nouns led me to read it just as the other guy calling him by the wrong name. Though I agree, it's not terribly funny either way. One wonders why anybody ever thought this worth publishing.

Comment: @A.R. The practice of italicizing **and** initial-capping most proper names (for example, country names and people's last names) was widespread in seventeenth- and eighteenth-century publishing, so this isn't a quirk of this particular author. I guess you'd have to read "Biship _Olim_" as something like "Bishop _Former_" where _Former_ becomes the bishop's actual last name. Ho-ho. But, of course, that joke wouldn't be entirely capturable in direct speech in any case, unless the random guy made air-quote marks and an underline slash with his hands.

Comment: Indeed, many of the jokes go to such extremes to set up barely funny punchlines that the effort is in itself funny (to me, anyway). I do love [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytZPv.jpg), though. "Yo dawg, I heard thou likest Ruffes..."

Comment: Just want to reply to Peter, who commented on the first word of a page being printed at the bottom of the previous page. That is a "catchword," printed not to assist the reader, but as an aid to the printer and bookbinder for collating pages and signatures into the final bound volume. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catchword